# DecisionTree - Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am new to this, anything will be helpful. The data size is large...
I am not sure where the error could be coming from. I dont even know if this is a good idea hahah, I am using longitude and latitude for my x and y.

````
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('aug.csv')
X = df.Lon
y = df.Lat

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)```

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-73.9713 -74.0635 -73.9881 ... -74.1777 -73.9923 -73.9661].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
````

Comment: Two dimensional array is an array within an array. It is an array of arrays. For example T = [[111, 222, 333, 444], [15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12, 5], [12,15,8,6]].

Answer (score 0):

Your X variable for the inputs needs to be an array of features. You have a single column in that csv so it interprets that as a 1D array. The error message you are getting is correct, so change that line "X = df.Lon" to be:
"X = df.Lon.reshape(-1, 1)"

One thing to note: what you're doing doesn't make a ton of sense. What this code is trying to do is predict the Y (lat) given the X (lon). These really should be independent variables, so predicting one from the other will probably not yield any meaningful results.